# Can factorial be bounded by the double exponential function?

Tags: exponential-function, factorial

I suspect this is the case, unlike the single-exponential case, but can you give a proof for:

$$ n! < 2^{2^n} $$ ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you could try a proof by induction and ask where you stuck.

Comment: Have a look at Stirling's formula if you haven't already.

Comment: Hint: $$n!=1\times\dots\times n<n\times\dots\times n=n^n\ll2^{2^n}$$

Comment: though the answers already show it can be proven another argument to help come to the conclusion would be that n! only has a certain number of factors of two you can pull out of it. for the even numbers, we have that they contribute at least  $$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor log_2n\rfloor}\left \lfloor {n\over2^i}\right \rfloor$$ 2's we can add about the same with odd numbers, and about the same with odd divisors of even numbers. But that is at very least likely less than $2^n$ the number of 2's we'd need to extract for them to equal or to change the inequality sign around.

Answer (score 2):

One can easily see your statement holds for $n=0$ and $n=1$. Moreover, the quotients are
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}=n+1, \quad \frac{2^{2^{n+1}}}{2^{2^n}}=2^{2^n}. $$
This shows that the factorial grows at a slower rate, proving the inequality (formally, you need to make this into a proof by induction).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by induction if we use the fact that $2^{2^n} > n+1$

$$1 = 1! < 2^{2^n} = 2^2 = 4$$

Now we have if $n! < 2^{2^n}$ that

$$2^{2^{n+1}} = 2^{2^n + 2^n} = 2^{2^n}2^{2^n} > 2^{2^n} n! > (n+1)n!$$

Then by induction the result follows.

The fact that $2^{2^n}>n$ also follows from induction since. $2^{2^1} = 4 > 2$ and if $2^{2^n} > n$ we have

$$2^{2^{n+1}} = 2^{2^n + 2^n} = 2^{2^n}2^{2^n} > 2^{2^n}(n+1) > 4(n+1) > n+2$$